# How to use the .any? method in ruby to return true if there is a string in the array

Tags: ruby, methods, block

I am trying to create an any_strings? method that takes an array and returns true if there is a string in the array. For example:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, "string" ]
any_strings?(a)
#=> true

b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
any_strings?(b)
#=> false
```

Define any_strings? as follows:

```
def any_strings?(a)
end
```

Am I supposed to use the is_a? method,  I am quite confused with how exactly you use 2 block methods

Comment: What is your question? Have you read the documentation for [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard.

```
def any_strings?(array)
  array.any? { |element| element.is_a?(String) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy to do in point-free style:

```
def any_strings?(array)
  array.any?(&String.method(:===))
end
```

Comment: I'm curious whether you would use this example in production code, or are you showing it in order to educate?  I find the... er... pointed... style to be easier to read in this case.